# ls command, default (alphabetical) sorting order

Tags: sorting, ascii, ls

here a piece of code :

```
$> ls
`  =  _  ;  ?  (  ]  @  \  %  1  4  7  a  B  d  E  g  H  J  l  M  o  P  r  S  u  V  x  Y
^  >  -  :  '  )  {  $  &  +  2  5  8  A  c  D  f  G  i  k  L  n  O  q  R  t  U  w  X  z
<  |  ,  !  "  [  }  *  #  0  3  6  9  b  C  e  F  h  I  K  m  N  p  Q  s  T  v  W  y  Z
```

I'm printing all ASCII character, each element is a folder, and I'm trying to understand the default sorting order of the ls command.

I understand that's there is a case insensitive comparison to sort alphabetic character, with digit coming first.

I've some trouble to understand how special character are sorted, and I'm not able to find something clear. I was thinking it could be related to the ASCII table, but when we see how things are ordered it really make no sens with it... Where is this order coming from ?

Thanks